# Creating and setting typedef struct values in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, variables, struct, set, typedef

I have a class in a game that is often used, and I thought it would be nice to tidy it up by grouping together instance variables with a typedef struct. I'm not completely convinced yet this will help or not.

**Originally in my class header interface I had something like this:**

```
@interface ThingClass : CCLayer {

     @public

          bool _invulnerableToggled;
          int _invulnerableCount;
          int _invulnerableMax;

}

@property(nonatomic, assign) bool invulnerableToggled;
@property(nonatomic, assign) int invulnerableCount;
@property(nonatomic, assign) int invulnerableMax;
```

and in my .m

```
@synthesize

invulnerableToggled = _invulnerableToggled,
invulnerableCount = _invulnerableCount,
invulnerableMax = _invulnerableMax;
```

A subclass of this class would set these variables to their default values in init.  Another class could access an instance of this subclass and set the values accordingly with regular dot notation, like tempThing.invulnerableToggled = YES;

Now that I'm using a typedef struct, it looks as though my values cannot be adjusted, and I've tried various things to overcome it. Although it may be because I'm not setting this up correctly to begin with, so just in case I'll show you what I'm doing now.

**Currently my class header:**

```
typedef struct {

    bool toggled;
    int count;
    int max;

} Invulnerable;

@interface ThingClass : CCLayer {

     @public
          Invulnerable _invulnerable;

}

@property(nonatomic, assign) Invulnerable invulnerable;
```

and in my .m

```
@synthesize

invulnerable = _invulnerable;
```

I set these values in a subclass init like so:

```
_invulnerable.toggled = NO;
_invulnerable.count = 0;
_invulnerable.max = 50;
```

When I try to set this in another class, I expect it to add 1 to the current value.  It always remains 1 instead.  This if statement is sometimes checked 60 times a second, but has not change to the count:

```
Invulnerable invulnerable = tempBaddy.invulnerable;

// check baddy invulnerability and increment if needed

if(invulnerable.toggled == YES){

    int increase = invulnerable.count +1;

    invulnerable.count = increase;

    NSLog(@"invulnerable.count = %i", invulnerable.count);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to pass-by-value in C!

Comment: You create a local varialbe of that struct. Then assign (copy the values in this case) the values of tempBaddy.invulnerable. Then you increase the value of a member of the local copy. But you never copy that increased value back to tempBaddy.invulnerable - as far as we can see. Next time it starts over again with the unchanged value of tempBaddy.invulnerable copied into a newly created local variable etc. pp.

Comment: Why don't you make invulnerable a class that holds 4 properties? In the end a class is not much more than a struct either but you can deal with it the way you are used to.

Comment: Hermann, it looks like all I have do in the end is tempBaddy.invulnerable = invulnerable; but couldn't it be easier? The class sounds like a good idea if it isn't too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a common way in ObjC but you can pass the struct by reference, i.e. return a pointer to the struct:

```
@interface ThingClass : CCLayer {
@protected
    Invulnerable _invulnerable;
}

@property(nonatomic, readonly) Invulnerable* invulnerable;

@end
```

The *.m file:

```
@implementation ThingClass

- (Invulnerable*)invulnerable {
    return &_invulnerable;
}

@end
```

Updating the data:

```
Invulnerable* invulnerable = tempBaddy.invulnerable;
// check baddy invulnerability and increment if needed
if(invulnerable->toggled == YES){
    invulnerable->count++;
    NSLog(@"invulnerable.count == %i", tempBaddy.invulnerable->count);
}
```

**I guess** you are trying to perform some action on an instance of ThingClass (or its subclass). And the action affects the value of _invulnerable. In this case a more common way would be having a method in the Thing class that performs all the required updates:

```
@implementation ThingClass

- (void)headshot {
    if (_invulnerable.toggled) {
        _invulnerable.count++;

    } else {
        [self die];
    }
}

@end
```